# php pdo bind parameter not working

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm using the following php pdo code to insert data into mysql database, the insertion succeeded, however, the updated database is showing the string literals ':a', ':b' as values in respectively field.  what's wrong?

```
  
$data = array(
  array('a' => 'John', 'b' => 'OK'),

);
    $st=$dbh->prepare("insert into mytable (a, b) values(':a', ':b')");
    $st->execute($data) or print_r($st->errorInfo());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the quotes from your placeholders.  Otherwise, they are treated as string literals and directly inserted.

```
$st=$dbh->prepare("insert into mytable (a, b) values(:a, :b)");
```

And remove the nesting on your array:

```
// $data is an associative array, it should not contain another array!
$data = array('a' => 'John', 'b' => 'OK');
```

To be consistent, I prefer to use the `:` on the placeholder array keys:

```
$data = array(':a' => 'John', ':b' => 'OK');
```

Comment: now I get $st->errorInfo() showing without detailed error msg:  Array
(
    [0] => HY093
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
)

Comment: @user121196 I see it now -  you have a nested array `$data`, when it should be a single array.  See addition above.

Comment: I've put nearly 12 hours into trying to solve this bug. Thank you, @MichaelBerkowski!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your array the same in the sql and the parameters, you're missing the ":". You also don't need two arrays, only one.

```
$data = array(':a' => 'John', ':b' => 'OK');
```

The query also does not need quotes, since PDO already knows it's a parameter

```
$st=$dbh->prepare("insert into mytable (a, b) values(:a, :b)");
$st->execute($data) or print_r($st->errorInfo());
```

Comment: I believe the actually work with or with the `:`, even though it isn't documented.

Comment: @Developer: i tried with :, it didn't make a difference.. in fact I used $st->bindParam(":a", "test"), it didn't make any difference...

Comment: Remove the quotes from the parameters values(:a, :b) and not values(':a', ':b')

Comment: It's because your parameter is a nested array, you only need one array

Answer (score 0):

You are executing a prepared statement with named placeholders. So, you need to remove quotes from your placeholders, otherwise they are treated as a values for respective columns and directly updated.

To be consistent, I prefer to use the : on the placeholder array keys:

```
$data = array(':a' => 'John', ':b' => 'OK'); 

$st=$dbh->prepare("insert into mytable (a, b) values(:a, :b)");
```

You can also execute a prepared statement with question mark placeholders:

```
$data = array(
  array('John','OK'),

);
$st=$dbh->prepare("insert into mytable (a, b) values(?, ?)");
$st->execute($data) or print_r($st->errorInfo());
```